# Why does JBoss deploy my eclipse project as a war in addition to my ear?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss7.x

I'm developing a Java project in Eclipse and running it on JBoss 7 from inside Eclipse. When I run my project I get the following in the console:

> 10:13:20,050 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service
>   thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "tcTrunkJBoss7.war"
>
> 10:13:20,063 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service
>   thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "takecargo.ear"

I really just want to deploy the ear. Where is it defined that my entire project (project name in Eclipse: "tcTrunkJBoss7") will deploy as a war?

Comment: EARs only holds packaged stuff.  Your project needs to be put in a WAR to be able to be put inside an EAR.  Note that some containers can handle "exploded" WAR's and EARS.  Then the filestructure just need to be in place.

Comment: Ok, I'm embarrassed. The reason I was seeing that line was because it had been deployed earlier in some incorrect way and so JBoss was simply deploying the exploded folder tcTrunkJBoss7.war that was present here:
/path/to/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments

I removed that folder and it obviously didn't show up during the next startup.

Comment: I figured out exactly what was going on--why the tcTrunkJBoss7 was appearing in the deployments folder as an exploded war folder: tcTrunkJBoss7.war. I was deploying the project by right clicking on the project in Eclipse and choosing "Run as > Run on Server". My ant build file already puts the ear file in the deployments folder so all I really need to do is click the JBoss icon/button up in the menu (far left), choose the server, e.g. JBoss 7.1, then click the "Play" button.

Answer (score 0):

EAR stands for Enterprise Archive which can contains atleast one or more WARs(Web archives), thing is what you deploy on the server is ear but it contains war so it is giving you that log.